# Loop through pre defined values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, for-loop, plsql

Is there a way to do a "for each" in oracle, something like this:

```
begin
  for VAR in {1,2,5}
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('The value: '||VAR);
  end loop;
end;
```

I know you can do something like:

```
begin
  for VAR in 1..5
  loop
    if VAR in(1,3,5) then
      dbms_output.put_line('The value: '||VAR);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

But isn't there a way to do this in a nicer way? Defining a set of values and iterating through them?

Thanks.

Comment: Put the list of values in a table. You can now loop through the values in the table using a cursor.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could do this, though probably not as slick as you'd like:

```
declare
  type nt_type is table of number;
  nt nt_type := nt_type (1, 3, 5);
begin
  for i in 1..nt.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(nt(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

If you create a type in the database:

```
create type number_table is table of number;
```

then you can do this:

```
begin
  for r in (select column_value as var from table (number_table (1, 3, 5))) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.var);
  end loop;
end;
```

Also, as A.B.Cade has commented below there are database types that come with Oracle that you can use, such as `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll`:

```
begin
  for r in (select column_value as var from table (dbms_debug_vc2coll (1, 3, 5))) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.var);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to create a type in the DB, you can do `for r in (select column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(1,3,5))) loop`

Comment: @A.B.Cade - Please make this an answer so it'll get proper visibility. I'll add it as an answer myself if you don't within a few days.

Answer (score 17):

This comes from A.B.Cade's comment on the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798366/901641), but I find it a lot cleaner and deserving of more attention:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(1, 3, 5))) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i.column_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. For anyone need solution for strings values: It can pass strings as parameters, too  `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('a', 'b', 'c')`